# Applications of visual calculus

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, plane-geometry, applications

Mamikon's *visual calculus* (see [Mamikon](http://www.cco.caltech.edu/%7Emamikon/calculus.html), [Tom Apostol](http://www.cco.caltech.edu/%7Emamikon/VisualCalc.html), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_calculus)) is a very beautiful and surprisingly efficient tool.

The basis is

> **Mamikon's theorem.** The area of a tangent sweep is equal to the area of its tangent cluster, regardless of the shape of the original curve.

For a nice picture, see [this](http://www.cco.caltech.edu/%7Emamikon/IknVary.html), and the following picture from [Apostol's introduction](http://www.cco.caltech.edu/%7Emamikon/VisualCalc.html):

[image] [<sup>(source: Wayback Machine)</sup>](https://web.archive.org/web/20120206220048im_/http://www.cco.caltech.edu/%7Emamikon/Fig24.gif)

The above links provide interesting applications, like very easy ways to find the area of a [cycloid](http://www.cco.caltech.edu/%7Emamikon/CycloIkon.html) and [tractrix](http://www.cco.caltech.edu/%7Emamikon/TraxIkon.html).

> **Question.**
>
> 1. What are other new applications?
> 2. Are there new developments of visual calculus?
> 3. What are some similar visual results, which can simplify calculations, and can be included in visual calculus?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but Mamikon's theorem leads to an appealing solution to the following (popular) calculus problem, while the standard solution is rather brute force: http://media.cheggcdn.com/media/477/4771238a-5509-4127-9233-7aafd34c0799/phpShF937.png

Comment: @Dustin G. Mixon: that's a cool application, and I think it can be made into an answer.

Comment: @Cristi Stoica: Done.

Comment: I honestly didn't think I'd ever learn anything about calculus this new to me at this stage in my education.

Comment: very nice result! That would bring some 'fun' back to mathematical education, but I almost fear that reasons for not presenting it in the class room will be the same as the one's for not anticipating it back in 1959.

Answer (score 9):

Mamikon's theorem leads to an appealing solution to the following (popular) calculus problem, while the standard solution is rather brute force:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this previous MO question may help:
[Taking “Zooming in on a point of a graph” seriously](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77175/taking-zooming-in-on-a-point-of-a-graph-seriously),
e.g., this [answer link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77175/taking-zooming-in-on-a-point-of-a-graph-seriously/77227#77227).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that the following is what you are looking for but I hope that it sheds some useful light on the topic of your query and suggests further applications.  Given a curve
in the plane with parametrisation $(c_1(u),c_2(u))$ one can consider the transformation $$F(u,v)=(c_1(u)+\sqrt {2 v} \dot c_1(u),c_2(u)+\sqrt {2 v}\dot c_2(u)).$$
(We are actually interested in the network this mapping introduces in the plane---the image of the coordinate network---which has a natural geometrical interpretation related to the OP).  A simple computation shows that the determinant of the Jacobi matrix of this mapping is $\ddot c_1(u)\dot c_2(u)-\dot c_1(u)\ddot c_2(u))$.  From this we can deduce various useful facts:

$1.$  The parametrisation $c$ does not appear explicitly (only its derivatives).  This is the reason for the satement at the start of the OP.

$2.$  The determinant is independent of $v$ (this was the reason for the strange dependence of $F$ on $v$).  In particular we can choose a parametrisation for $c$ for which this is identically $1$ which means that $F$ is area-preserving.  This can be used to garner a plethora of results for particular curves.

$3.$  The case of the cycloid has some special features which explains some results and methods in the works quoted  If we use the standard parametrisation $(t-\sin t,1-\cos t)$, then the above determinant is $1-\cos t$ which is just the height of the given point above the $x$-axis.

Much more could be said about this topic, but we would like to close with the remark that these facts were not just pulled out of thin air---behind them there lies an important concept, that of a Samuelson configuration, which was introduced by the economics laureate Paul Samuelson (not under that name, of course) in his Nobel acceptance speech, i.e., over 40 years ago.